# Find the derivatives to transformed variables

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

Let $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$  and consider the rotational action
$X = x \cos\theta - y \sin\theta$ ; $Y = x \sin\theta  + y \cos\theta$. 
Find the transformed derivatives $Y'$ and $Y''$.

How do I approach this question. What am I supposed to be differentiating with respect to?

The second part is to show the infinitesimals associated with $x, y, y' \text{and }
y''$ of which I am able to do using a different method, but i need to work from the transformed derivatives.

If anybody know any reads that will help me out could you please tell me.

Comment: Does this help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative

Comment: Not so much. Thank you though.

Comment: What does $Y'$ and $Y' '$ stand for? Are you differentiating with respect to time, like Tony suggested? If so, can we assume $\theta$ is constant? This means that your post-transform $X$ and $Y$ would simply have derivatives multiplied by $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$.

Answer (score 1):

It comes in my mind O.Toeplitz *The Calculus - A Genetic Approach* (2007 edition) pp.144-145.

There it is proved that the concept of acceleration does not depend on the coordinate system, considering $x$ and $y$ as functions of time and differentiating w.r.t. the latter.

Try to read and let me know.